# Add user custom field check to Moodle login page

Tags: php, authentication, moodle

I have custom user profile field `Faculty`.

I want to check it in the user login page, if the user is not assigned as `Faculty` returned to login page.
How can I do this?

Comment: Where the user exactly set the `Faculty` value? while the registration or where ?!

Comment: @AshrafHefny When admin register users set true for faculty. this show taht user is teacher.

Comment: So the users are registered by admin and you want to check if the `Faculty` is `true/false` while login ?

Comment: @AshrafHefny Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Moodle Events API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Event_2) to trigger an event while logging 
The code will be something as the following 
Inside your plugin directory create `plugin/classes/observer.php` file 
Let's say your plugin is a clean theme, so the content of that file will be

```
class theme_clean_observer
{
    public static function update_loggedin(\core\event\user_loggedin $loggedin){
    //get user data by $loggedin
    // check faculty value
    // redirect to somewhere
    }
}
```

And create `plugin/db/events.php`:

```
$observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname'   => '\core\event\user_loggedin',
        'callback'    => '\theme_clean_observer::update_loggedin',
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple, when the user logs in run a code that checks if the user is a faculty user or not. You can use the link function to direct them to the specific page you want.

for example:

```
If($UserType == "Faculty"){ 
link ( "Home.php" )
}else{ 
link ( "Login.php" )
}
```